# How can I query and sort custom-post type using WP_Query

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, custom-field

guys, I have a custom post type called "game" and it has some custom fields (get_post_meta) which I access by their keys "_game_date_key", "_game_home_goals_key" and "_game_away_goals_key".

How do I use the WP_Query() to return posts sorted by the "_game_date_key" and ("_game_home_goals_key" and "_game_away_goals_key") are numbers ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add arguments to WP_Query to sort by your keys in the order you want. The compare value can be your filter (larger, smaller, etc)

```
$args = [
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        'event_start_date_clause' => array(
            'key'     => '_game_date_key',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS',
        ),
        'event_start_time_clause' => array(
            'key'     => '_game_home_goals_key',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS',
        ), 
        'event_start_time_clause' => array(
            'key'     => '_game_away_goals_key',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS',
        ),
     ),
    'orderby' => array(
        '_game_date_key' => 'ASC',
        '_game_home_goals_key' => 'ASC',
        '_game_away_goals_key' => 'ASC',
    ),
];
```

Comment: Didn't directly work but you gave me the approach thank you
```$args = [
    'post_type'=>'game',
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'orderby' =>'_game_date_key',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'=>'_game_home_goals_key',
            'value'=>'',
            'compare'=>'!='
        ),
        array(
            'key'=>'_game_away_goals_key',
            'value'=>'',
            'compare'=>'!='
        )
    )
];``` that's the one I used

Comment: What if I have a date string inside how do I sort it as a date, not a normal string?